# android 10 seek bar on notification

Tags: android, notifications, seekbar

does anyone know about the seekbar function on notifications in android 10?

I can't seem to get the position indicator to show the current position.
the bar is just blank but I can seek the media clicking the bar in the notification.

I have the normal notification builder code and I have added this to make the seekbar clickable in the "MediaPlayer.Event.Playing"  event of libvlc

```
MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();


metadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, mMediaPlayer.getLength());

PlaybackStateCompat.Builder mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING,  1, 1.0f)
        .setBufferedPosition(mMediaPlayer.getLength())
        .setActions(
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO |
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);


mediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
```

the media playing is about half way but there is no indicator of its position.

[image: notification]

Comment: This only appears to happen to certain devices where on other devices the seek bar will display perfectly fine.

Additionally on the same device other media players have perfectly fine displaying seek bars, such as Youtube, Youtube Red, Google Play Music, etc.

I am not sure what is causing this as I am also affected on one device however on another device issue is not present.

Comment: The problem is in the small notification icon. Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545791/1775228

Answer (score 9):

After searching for a long time, eventually I came up with the solution.
Please take the below steps to have the SeekBar displayed in your notification in Android 10 or higher.

- Step 1: Put the duration of your file in *milliseconds* as a `Long` value with the key `MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION` in your  `MediaSession.setMetadata`

```
mediaSession.setMetadata(MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
    .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, resource)
    .putString(
        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST,
        activeBookFile.title
    )
    .putString(
        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM,
        AudioPlayerService.activeBook.title
    )
    .putString(
        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE,
        AudioPlayerService.activeBook.title
    )
    .putLong(
        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION,
        activeBookFile.duration
    )
    .build()
)
```

- Step 2: Add `ACTION_SEEK_TO` to all your `PlaybackStateCompat.setAction()` methods
- Step 3: Provide a valid currentPosition in *millseconds* and the current state of your playing item then pass them to
  `PlaybackStateCompat.setState()` method.
- Step 4: Set the playBackState object to your mediaSession using `setPlaybackState()`

```
fun updateMediaPlaybackState(currentPos: Long) {
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(
        PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO
            )
            .setState(
                getPlaybackState(),
                currentPos,
                1f,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            )
            .build()
    )
}
```

```
@PlaybackStateCompat.State
private fun getPlaybackState(): Int {
        return when (currentState) {
            is PlayerStoppedState -> PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED
            is PlayerPausedState -> PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED
            is PlayerResumingState -> PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING
            is PlayerLoadingState, is PlayerBufferingState -> PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_BUFFERING
            is PlayerErrorState -> PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_ERROR
            else -> PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE
        }
    }
```

- Step 5: To support user touch on the SeekBar override `onSeekTo(pos: Long)` method in `MediaSessionCompat.Callback()`

```
class PlayerMediaSessionCallback(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer?) : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

// other callback methods

    override fun onSeekTo(pos: Long) {
        mediaPlayer?.seekTo(pos)
    }
}
```

- **Note**: Remember to call `updateMediaPlaybackState()` and `showNotification()` whenever a state change happened for your player(paly, pause, skipNext, skipPrevious, seek, etc.)

Comment: @JonathanF. You're welcome. So glad that it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

update: it does appear to be showing the position but it is hard to see when the color of the notification is dark.
for some reason the seekbar is not inverting its color based on the notification color.

if anyone comes across this problem make the background of the notification white and look to see if it is tracking the position.

so now i need to figure out how to get the bar to display a light color on a dark background

[image: notification]

Answer (score 0):

You need add small icon with white color. You shouldn't use icon with other colors.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_white)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the current position of the song like this
`.setState(if (isPlaying()) PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING else PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, getCurrentPosition().toLong(), 1f)`

**Example-**

```
val stateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(MEDIA_SESSION_ACTIONS)
            .setState(
                if (isPlaying()) PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING else PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED,
                getCurrentPosition().toLong(), 1f
            )

        mediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())
```

**Note**: Above codes are in Kotlin