# Android 10 MediaStyle Notification Seek Bar is Black

Tags: android, exoplayer

The MediaStyle Notification introduced in Android 10 works but is however black and doesn't display duration either.

[image: Android 10 Media Style Notification with Black Seek Bar]

Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/ryanheise/audioservice/AudioService.java

Reference another question: [android 10 seek bar on notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516981/android-10-seek-bar-on-notification)

This only appears to happen to certain devices where on other devices the seek bar will display perfectly fine.

Additionally on the same device other media players have perfectly fine displaying seek bars, such as Youtube, Youtube Red, Google Play Music, etc.

Comment: Sir, this is not a bug tracker, but your post looks like a bug report.
Please specify what you have tried so far. Giving a link to a 764 lines of code cannot help other to answer you question.

Comment: Here is a reference to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516981/android-10-seek-bar-on-notification

This only happens on certain devices so it is hard to debug. My device has a black bar however a different device will have a correct seekbar

Comment: So you basically opened two identical posts with same question?

Comment: updated the original post to include more context of what is happening. This is possibly not a bug but a misconfiguration in the code. Hard to determine where because the issue is only present on one device for me not others. The one device being a Samsung.

Comment: Testing on another device, OnePlus 6T. This issue is not there and the seek bar is displayed perfectly fine.

Comment: Great. I would suggest you going this approach: find an open source app which has that feature in place, for example I believe Telegram also has audio playback feature and it's open source.

Comment: Another one - [Shuttle](https://github.com/timusus/Shuttle).

Answer (score 5):

I followed the hints reported in [this](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/289) bug report and I solved the problem. I successfully tested it on Samsung and Huawei devices with Android 10.

The trick is:

> As per Google's Material Design guidelines, the small icon in the
> notification should be monochrome white, and have a transparent
> background. If you follow those guidelines, the slider displays
> correctly.

Some people report also that you have to set a non transparent color (like `Color.BLACK`) using `setColor()` method to make it work on some devices.

Comment: You saved my life! I lost the whole day on this. And why would be notification icon related to seekbar? :-/